# How to remove white space in server side DATATABLE when use Ajax?

Tags: jquery, datatable, serverside-datatable

I'm new in server side data table. I have problem when i use Ajax than page lode showing white Design Any solution for this Problem ?

I'm shared Screenshot of white Space.

Problem :- [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uU9YJ.png)

Original DataTable :- [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Of3Lq.png)

My Code :-

```
 $('#airplay-type, #airplay-country, #airplay-station, #airplay-duration').on("change", function() {
var type = $('#airplay-type').val()
        var country = $('#airplay-country').val()
        var station = $('#airplay-station').val()
        var duration = $('#airplay-duration').val()
        $('#airplay-side-table').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "pagin": false,
        "destroy": true,
        "ajax":{
        "url": "{{ url('label/artist/ajax/airplaydetails') }}",
                "dataType": "json",
                "type": "POST",
                "data":{ _token: "{{csrf_token()}}", type: type, country: country, station: station, duration: duration}
        },
        "columns": [
        { "data": "rank" },
        { "data": "evolution" },
        { "data": "previous_rank" },
        { "data": "songdetails" },
        { "data": "label" },
        { "data": "release_date" },
        { "data": "play_count" },
        { "data": "previous_evolution" },
        { "data": "reach" },
        ]

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.dataTables_wrapper {
   _height: 102px;
   min-height: 102px;
}
```

Comment: add the table class above code

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.